# How to turn off warning: "[warn] Choosing local for xxx"

Tags: scala, sbt

When working with multiple sbt projects (of which some are **only locally** published), I always get a compiler warning stating `[warn] Choosing local for com.github.fbaierl.#myLib_2.12;2.0.0-SNAPSHOT`.

This, of course, happens when compiling projects which have this library as a debendency in their `build.sbt`:

```scala
libraryDependencies += "com.github.fbaierl" %% "myLib" % "2.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

Everything works like the way it should, but I was wondering if I could get rid of warnings like these if I somehow state that taking the local version of a library is the correct way in my `build.sbt`. Since I am not planning on ever releasing these libraries to Maven I would be stuck with these warnings forever otherwise.